# Using generic array name in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am really new to vue.js and HTML. I have two components that are working together. A photo-gallery and a tag-component. The tag-component uses the tags array to get the tags for a image. What i would like is to have a tag array for each image. I figured i could use the `imageIndex` and append that to the array name so I was string something like *`:tags=tags+imageIndex`*.

But if I do that, it does not work (i think it is not recognized as an array any more...) . My question is, is there a way to enter that in to the template, so that i have for each image an array with the name *`tags{index}`*?

Many thanks for the help!

Robin

```
<div id="SingleFile">
    <button
            id="refreshbtn"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-margin"
            @click="updateFileList">
        refresh
    </button>

    <gallery :images="images" :index="index" @close="index = null"></gallery>
    <div
            :key="imageIndex"
            :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + image + ')', width: '300px', height: '200px' }"
            @click="index = imageIndex"
            class="image"
            v-for="(image, imageIndex) in images"

    >
        <div>
        <vue-tags-input
                v-model="tag"
                :tags="tags"
                @tags-changed="newTags => tags = newTags"
        />
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="upload">
    <upload-image url="http://localhost:8080/user" name="files" max_files="100"></upload-image>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a method to achieve that:

```
     <vue-tags-input
            v-model="tag"
            :tags="getTags(imageIndex)"  ... >
```

and define it like :

```
  methods:{
      getTags(i){
       return this['tags'+i];
       }
    }
```

by assuming that you have in your data object something like :

```
   data(){
      return{
          tags0:[],
          tags1:[],
          ...
        }
  }
```

or any property which has that syntax `tags+index`

Comment: thanks so much! It works exactly like i need it! In the method i will make the api calls and give back the arrays directly